# Bitbake Setting BBPATH: command not found

Tags: path, ubuntu-18.04, yocto, bitbake

I'm comparatively new to Ubuntu and bitbake.  Working my way through 'Bitbake User Manual (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html). Yocto version is sumo (git checkout tags/yocto-2.4.1 -b poky_2.4.1); ubuntu 18.04 version.

Trying to set BBPATH for my project directory (step 3), as:

```
BBPATH = "/home/benjamin/Documents/c code/helloWorld"
```

Error:

```
BBPATH: command not found
```

All else is working fine, so far.  The echo $PATH command shows:

```
/home/benjamin/digikey/poky/bitbake/bin
/home/benjamin/digikey/poky/bitbake/lib
/home/benjamin/digikey/poky/build/conf
```

The ./conf directory has the as-yet unedited *.conf files:

```
local.conf
bblayers.conf
```

At /home/benjamin, the command:

```
bitbake --version
```

returns

```
BitBake Build Tool Core version 1.38.0
```

So, that's good.  Please give me a hint on setting BBPATH.

Comment: go to poky directory. cd poky; source oe-init-build-env and then try bitbake commands

Comment: Your suggestions were executed as part of installation.  In the ~/poky/build/conf/ directory, bitbake -h returns info on commands.  I think I needed to create a layer.conf file in ~/poky/build/conf/.  My question concerns the information in layer.conf (which defines BBPATH) and LAYERDIR)...Do I have to change LAYERDIR in layer.conf for every new project?  Do I mkdir mylayer at the ~/home layer?

Comment: You should have bblayer.conf that looks like [this](https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-base/blob/master/conf/bblayers.conf) and layers.conf like [this](https://github.com/Freescale/meta-freescale/blob/master/conf/layer.conf#L2)

Comment: Hello, Nayle.  I took your advice, and found bbylayers.conf on my Ubuntu OS; I could not find the layers.conf file.  I used the terminal command locate -i [fileName].  I found 3 bblayers.conf files, only one of which resembled the file at your Githuub link.  A few questions: should there be only one bblayers.conf file?  I read that project code (e.g., HelloWorld) should have its own directory - one of the bblayers.conf files.  Also, where should I place the github bblayer.conf file?  Same question for the layers.conf file.  I can provide the full paths to each bblayer.conf file.

Comment: `bblayer.conf` should be in `build/conf` folder and specify layers to use for current build. There is as many `bblayer.conf` as build folders. Generally, `bblayers.conf` file is put in a `template` folder and copied to build folder with oe init script. Each yocto layer has a `meta-x/conf/layer.conf` that append BBPATH to layer path, add recipes to BBFILES, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You may update your bblayer.conf file as so

```
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/path_to_layer "
```

you may then use bitbake to compile

eg:

```
bitbake name-of-recipe
```

Here are a few references

https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-331917

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmrHAHADoI8